# Missing arguments for parameters even when initialised

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to call a detailed view of an item when an item is tapped. In this case, the item is a pair of trousers in the MarketplaceTrouserView. When I call TrouserDetailView, I get an error. This must be to do with initialising but I've repeatedly tried this and failed. What could be the solution?

MarketplaceTrouserView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MarketplaceTrouserView: View {
   
    @StateObject var MarketplaceModel = MarketplaceViewModel()
    @State private var selectedMarketplaceFilter: MarketplaceFilterViewModel = .trouser
    @State var showDetailTrouser = false
    @State var selectedTrouser : Trouser!
    @EnvironmentObject var sharedData: SharedDataModel
    
    var body: some View {
        
        var columns = Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible()), count: 2)
        
        ZStack{  
            VStack{        
                HStack {
                    
                    Text("Find Trousers To Buy")
                }
                    }
            }                
                if MarketplaceModel.trousers.isEmpty{
                    
                    ProgressView()
                }
                else{
                    
                    ScrollView {

                        LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(),spacing: 10), count: 2),spacing: 20){
                            
                            ForEach(MarketplaceModel.filteredTrouser){trouser in
                                
                                // Trouser items in grid view 
                                
                                    TrouserView(trouserData: trouser)
                                    

                                        .onTapGesture {
                                            
                                            withAnimation {
 
                                                selectedTrouser = trouser
                                                showDetailTrouser.toggle()
                                            }
                                        }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            if selectedTrouser != nil && showDetailTrouser{
                
                TrouserDetailView(/*Here is the error asking for trouserData & showDetailTrouser*/)
                
            }
       }
}

}
```

TrouserDetailView:

```
import SwiftUI
import SDWebImageSwiftUI

struct TrouserDetailView: View {
    @State var trouserData : Trouser
    @State var showDetailTrouser: Bool
    @EnvironmentObject var sharedData: SharedDataModel    
    @EnvironmentObject var marketplaceData: MarketplaceViewModel
       
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
    ScrollView {
        
        VStack{
            
            HStack {
                
                Button(action: {

                                        withAnimation(.easeOut){showDetailTrouser.toggle()}

                                    }) {
                                        Image(systemName: "arrow.backward.circle.fill")

                                    }

                
                    Text(trouserData.trouser_name)
            }
            
            VStack {
                
                WebImage(url: URL(string: trouserData.trouser_image))   

            }
            
        }
    }
        }
```

Trouser Model:

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
import Firebase

struct Trouser: Identifiable, Codable {
    
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var trouser_name: String = ""
    var trouser_image: String = ""
}
```

The error is when i call TrouserDetailView (as marked in the code)

After applying changes, my MainPage view has errors in the initialiser.

MainPage

```
struct MainPage: View {

    @StateObject var appModel: AppViewModel = .init()
    
    @StateObject var sharedData: SharedDataModel = SharedDataModel()

    
    @State var shirtData : Shirt
    @State var showDetailShirt: Bool   
    @State var trouserData : Trouser
    @State var showDetailTrouser: Bool
    @Namespace var animation
    

    
    init () {
        
        @State var shirtData = Shirt()
        @State var showDetailShirt = false
        
        @State var trouserData = Trouser()
        @State var showDetailTrouser = false
       
        
        UITabBar.appearance().isHidden = true
    } //ERROR HERE: 'Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties'

    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {

            TabView(selection: $appModel.currentTab) {
                Marketplace()
                    .environmentObject(sharedData)
                    .tag(Tab.Market)
                    .setUpTab()
                
                Home()
                    .environmentObject(sharedData)
                    .tag(Tab.Home)
                    .setUpTab()
            }
```

Comment: Well yes, since you didn't provide a value for `trouserData` & `showDetailTrouser` the compiler is gonna ask for one. Maybe make them optional?

Comment: This seemed to have caused lots of errors in other areas of the project

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training

Comment: @Carrot That's what I'm trying to solve. Responses like this are not helpful

Answer (score 1):

By the logic of provided code, state is not needed for the first one and second should be replaced with binding, ie.

```
struct TrouserDetailView: View {
    var trouserData : Trouser
    @Binding var showDetailTrouser: Bool

    // ...
```

and call

```
if selectedTrouser != nil && showDetailTrouser {
    
    TrouserDetailView(trouserData: selectedTrouser, 
                showDetailTrouser: $showDetailTrouser)
    
}
```

Comment: I used Binding before and this made other areas of the code would break and I was told I should use State. Is there a way I can do this without using Binding?

Comment: State is for internal views states, but in the provided scenario external state is injected into child view and child view changes it, so injection should be done via binding.

Answer (score 0):

> @State var trouserData : Business
> @State var showDetailTrouser: Bool

These variables you must initialize the value locally or switch to `@Binding` to bind the data with the parent variables.

Comment: I see, how would I initialize these locally?

Comment: if `TrouserDetailView` data does not relate with `MarketplaceTrouserView`, then initialize the data locally; @State var trouserData : Business = Business(...),  @State var showDetailTrouser: Bool = false or true depends on your design.

Comment: This has made the errors disappear. I have the same issue on my MainPage view too. I made the same changes and the error disappeared there too. However, I now get an error in my initialiser in MainPage. I will update the code to demonstrate.